# how to add validation messages in volt?

Tags: ruby, voltrb

The volt docs refer to "client side validation" but there is no example code for this.

I have `volt-fields` set up with a validation like this:

```
validate :description, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 1000 }
```

then in my controller:

```
buffer.save!.then do |record|
  # javascript breakpoint here
end.fail do |err|
  # javascript breakpoint here
end
```

When I submit an object with an empty `description`, the `then` block is called. I would have expected the `fail` block to be called. Furthermore, I can't get access to the errors, if any are being added at all.

I've tried both `record.errors` and `record.server_errors` - both are empty as far as I can tell.

Do I need to write a custom validator, or can I use this built-in approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked about this and the feature is basically incomplete. Since the maintainer has no time to work on the project at this stage it will not be happening until someone else takes up maintaining the Volt framework.

Comment: thanks jesse. In your experience is volt a good choice at this time? or has it been growing more buggy as time goes on? I ended up trying to write my own client-side validation system but kept getting a mysterious error: `Undefined constant Volt::User` or something (i can't remember exactly what it is, would need to check). So I'm trying to decide if it's worth trying to build this medium-size app with Volt or if I should choose a different realtime framework (would likely be meteor). i do really like Ruby, though. I looked at hyperloop but I want something a bit more out-the-box.

Comment: In my experience Volt has only got better but the maintainer did most of the work which is probably why he didn't have time to work on it further so at the moment I would stay away from it. Honestly I really like writing code in Ruby I would suggest Rails as the framework and using the Opal gem for doing the Javascript (Volt was doing this under the hood)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion; it'd probably be sinatra for me.